# What does the brokerage function in R package network (sna, statnet) do with weights and mutual edges?

Tags: r, sna, statnet

The function `brokerage()` in R package `sna` performs a brokerage census following the [Gould and Fernandez 1989](https://www.jstor.org/stable/270949) article. The original Gould and Fernandez article only applies to directed binary networks. That is, edges have no weights. In addition, they do not demonstrate it for mutual edges. If we feed the `brokerage()` function with a network object that is directed, weighted, and containing mutual edges between nodes, the function returns a result nonetheless. The documentation does not detail, however, what the function does about weights and mutual edges. Does anyone know how the function handles it?